# Xray JSON results Automate execution with CI CD github pipeline Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, jira-xray, jfrog-xray, x-ray

I have written some test cases and i wanted to execute this test result to Jira/Xray. I didnt find any dart plugin for make json and import that result with xray api within github workflow.
Is there are any dart plugin or way we can achieve this?
Any Help and suggestion would be appreciate.
Thanks

I did try with JUnit output format but i wanted to achieve this with Xray Json api format api which is /rest/raven/1.0/import/execution.

Comment: Hi, to be able to better answer your question, can you please clarify why the JUnit XML report is not enough for you?  Any special reason to prefer the Xray JSON format instead?

Comment: As per document JUnit does't have any param for having execution with each steps and in Xray Json there's option for passing result for each steps of test.
is there are any way we can achieve same for JUnit too?

Comment: No. Unfortunately, JUnit XML schema doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no dart plugin (at least that I'm aware of) to generate Xray JSON reports.
However, you can integrate with Xray using JUnit XML reports as shown on the tutorials ahead. This will allow you to autoprovision Test issues whenever importing test results (if needed), and also track their overall status (e.g., pass/fail).

1. [tutorial for Xray on Jira cloud](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+Flutter+%28iOS%2C+Android%2C+web%2C+desktop%29+Applications)
2. [tutorial for Xray on Jira server/datacenter](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+Flutter+%28iOS%2C+Android%2C+web%2C+desktop%29+Applications)